# Переменная меняется и выводится на экран после каждого нажатия кнопки (python)

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы после каждого нажатия кнопки переменная менялась и выводилась на экран.

````
```
from tkinter import ttk
import random

root = Tk()     
root.title("Тест на концентрацию внимания")    
root.geometry("700x350")

a=3

b=0 

c=1

d=4

e=3

def press():
    global b
    if a<5:
        b+=1
        print(b)
        label.config(text=c)
    elif a==5:
        b=b
        print(b)
        label.config(text=c)
        
btn = ttk.Button(text="Кнопка", width=20, command = press)
btn.pack()

label=Label(text=a, font=('Times 70'), width=60, height=50)
label.pack()

root.mainloop ()
```
````

Пока что сделал так, но проблема в том, что переменная меняется только один раз.
Уверен, что можно сделать как-то по-другому, но не могу домыслить.
Не могли бы помочь?

Comment: вы выводите c, а оно не меняется в коде

Comment: Не совсем понял. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки выводилась новая цифра определенное количество раз, и при этом к b прибавлялось один

Comment: label.config(text=c) - тут вы водится c. как вы определяете, что происходит с b ?

Comment: 1 к b прибавляется, но мне не требуется выводить эту переменную, только в конце. Это можно сказать счет правильных ответов